# Grouping list by variables and counting sums of object variables

Tags: java, java-stream, mapping, grouping

I must group elements from given list using stream. I want to put them into map (do groupping by variable
'vat' <key=vat, value=list>), then count sum of every objects variable in each key.

I am being stuck in summing stream. I did groupping stream but now, after few hours of coding i still dont know what to do.

Code of function:

```
    public static List<Product> calculatingTaxes(List<Product> products){
        Map<Double, List<Product>> productTaxesMap = new HashMap<>();

        productTaxesMap = products.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getVat));

        System.out.println(productTaxesMap);
        return null;
    }
```

sout function is to see what the function is doing, current output

```
{1.0=[Product{netPrice=100.0, vat=1.0, vatAmount=0.0, grossPrice=100.0}, 
Product{netPrice=100.0, vat=1.0, vatAmount=0.0, grossPrice=100.0}], 1.23= 
[Product{netPrice=100.0, vat=1.23, vatAmount=23.0, grossPrice=123.0}, 
Product{netPrice=100.0, vat=1.23, vatAmount=23.0, grossPrice=123.0}, 
Product{netPrice=100.0, vat=1.23, vatAmount=23.0, grossPrice=123.0}], 1.08= 
[Product{netPrice=100.0, vat=1.08, vatAmount=8.0, grossPrice=108.0}, 
Product{netPrice=100.0, vat=1.08, vatAmount=8.0, grossPrice=108.0}]}
```

code of Product class:

```
public class Product {
private double netPrice;
private double vat;
private double vatAmount;
private double grossPrice;

public Product(double netPrice, double vat) {

    this.netPrice = netPrice;
    this.vat = vat;
    this.grossPrice = netPrice * vat;
    this.vatAmount = grossPrice - netPrice;
}

public double getNetPrice() {
    return netPrice;
}

public double getVatAmount() {
    return vatAmount;
}

public double getGrossPrice() {
    return grossPrice;
}

public double getVat() {
    return vat;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "netPrice=" + netPrice +
            ", vat=" + vat +
            ", vatAmount=" + vatAmount +
            ", grossPrice=" + grossPrice +
            '}';
}
```

I want the upper function, to return sum of netPrice, grossPrice and vat amount to every vat key(0-8-23%).
I tried collecting and summing elements using Collectors.grouppingBy(). by filtering etc, but none of them worked.

Comment: "then count sum of every objects variable in each key" Not sure what this means.

Comment: ah, its complicated form me to write. I mean : sum netPrice, gross and vatAmount (and save them as object )of 0-8-23% key,  for example: 23% vat key - obj1(netPrice 100, gross 123, vatAmount 23), obj2(netPrice 100, gross 123, vatAmount 23)- function should return obj3(netPrice 200, gross 269, vatAmount 69)

Comment: @JakubKołacz I think obj3 should be (netPrice 200, gross 246, vatAmount 46), no?

Comment: Yup you are right, i did a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input is:

```
List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
        new Product(100.0, 1.0),
        new Product(100.0, 1.0),
        new Product(100.0, 1.23),
        new Product(100.0, 1.23),
        new Product(100.0, 1.23),
        new Product(100.0, 1.08),
        new Product(100.0, 1.08)
);
```

You can do:

```
Map<Double, Product> vatToReducedProduct = products.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getVat,
                Function.identity(),
                (p1, p2) -> new Product(p1.getNetPrice() + p2.getNetPrice(), p1.getVat())));
```

Output:

```
{
 1.0=Product{netPrice=200.0, vat=1.0, vatAmount=0.0, grossPrice=200.0}, 
 1.23=Product{netPrice=300.0, vat=1.23, vatAmount=69.0, grossPrice=369.0}, 
 1.08=Product{netPrice=200.0, vat=1.08, vatAmount=16.0, grossPrice=216.0}
}
```